# ZPL Printer trimming the data when its in odd pairs

Tags: zpl

I have a barcode data:
^BY6,3,368^FT12,1032^BCN,,N,N
^FD>;00612345678^FS

What I am expecting the barcode to get scanned is 00612345678 but it is getting trimmed to 0061234567 everytime its scanned.

I tried to rebase the below code to

^BY6,3,368^FT12,1032^BCN,,N,N
^FD>:00612345678^FS

But didnt work

Comment: Code C (set by `>;`) only encodes pairs of digits, so your data will be truncated to an even number of digits - which is what you were seeing.  But the `>:` should have worked.  What do you mean by it "didn't work"?